# How to get data value inside function/$interval using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to get value inside of my function $interval and use it as interval time.

I have `index.html`:

```
<iframe src="{{MediaFile}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>
```

And `MediaFile` table:

```
+------+-------------+--------------+
|  ID  |   FileName  |    Interval  | //Interval in secs
+------+-------------+--------------+
|  1   |  image.jpg  |      30      |
+------+-------------+--------------+
|  2   |  image1.jpg |      10      |
+------+-------------+--------------+
|  3   |  video.mp4  |      50      |
+------+-------------+--------------+
```

And `index.js`:

```
// loadMediaFile, select the list of MediaFile in my table
loadMediaFile.MediaFiles('loadMediaFile').then(function (d) {
    $scope.IntervalTime = 2000;
    $scope.Count = -1;

    $interval(function () {
        $scope.Count++
        $scope.MediaFile = '/MediaFiles/Content/' + d[$scope.Count].FileName;

        $scope.IntervalTime = d[$scope.Count].Interval * 1000;

        // This is to load back to index 0 of my MediaFile when all is loaded
        if (d.length == ($scope.Count + 1)) {
            $scope.Count = -1;
        }

    }, $scope.IntervalTime);

    console.log($scope.IntervalTime);
})
```

Output should be:

```
Displays Image.jpg after 2secs
Displays Image1.jpg after 30
Displays Video.mp4 after 10
Displays Image.jpg after 50secs
```

The problem is the interval stays at 2 secs, it doesn't update the interval value since the correct value is inside of my $interval. That's why I want to return the correct value to $scope.IntervalTime like using the `return`.

Comment: Why interval? Go for the timeout, and invoke another timeout inside, then another etc.

Comment: @emix, actually I have stored data in my sql server contains pictures and interval time. I want to change displayed pictures based on their interval value and with default 2 secs interval for first picture.

Comment: @RichardCalumpang `$interval` is a Promise - an asynchronous callback. You can't extract any values from it _"outside"_, but you can keep your entire logic inside it. For example updating some counter, which will seemingly change your model in HTML code (like swap images in carousel because the counter went up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first `console.log` to show `11000`, put the increment operator (`++`) *before* the variable:

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶I̶n̶t̶e̶r̶v̶a̶l̶T̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶(̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶C̶o̶u̶n̶t̶+̶+̶)̶ ̶+̶ ̶1̶0̶)̶ ̶*̶ ̶1̶0̶0̶0̶;̶
$scope.IntervalTime = ((++$scope.Count) + 10) * 1000;
```

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.IntervalTime = 2000;
  $scope.Count = 0;
  timeoutFn();

  function timeoutFn() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.IntervalTime = ((++$scope.Count) + 10) * 1000;
      console.log($scope.IntervalTime)
      timeoutFn();
    }, $scope.IntervalTime/10);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    Count={{Count}}<br>
    IntervalTime={{IntervalTime}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$timeout` with recursive calling instead of `$interval`:

```js
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.IntervalTime = 2000;
  $scope.Count = 0;

 (function timeoutFn() {
    $timeout(function() {
       $scope.IntervalTime = (($scope.Count++) + 10) * 1000;
       console.log($scope.IntervalTime)
       timeoutFn();
    }, $scope.IntervalTime);
  })()
})
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working right.. just add `console.log()`

```
$scope.IntervalTime = 2000;
$scope.Count = 0

$interval(function () {
    $scope.IntervalTime = (($scope.Count++) + 10) * 1000;
    console.log("called :- "+$scope.IntervalTime);
    $scope.getValue($scope.IntervalTime);
}, $scope.IntervalTime);

$scope.getValue = function(tt){
    console.log("get value outside :- "+tt);
};

console.log("first time called :- "+$scope.IntervalTime);
```

Comment: It's not working, because I want to get the `called` value outside the function and use it as my next interval time. On my solution it always use the 2secs interval time which is the `first time called` value.

Comment: @georgeawg, the `$scope.getValue` put the value on another function. how can I make the $scope.IntervalTime = tt so that the next interval time will be the output.